# Google calendar api doesn't return all events c#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api

When i create a new event in google calendar and execute the code bellow that value doesn't gets returned.
Does it have something to do with the params that i need to give with the request?
Also I get a ok as statuscode so the request goes through always but it the content that it contains isn't complet it doesn't contain the new value in allEvents.

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetReservations([FromBody] Models.Reservation.Request.GetResourcesRequest request)
    {
        var schedulers = new List<Scheduler>();

        //alles van de turnup agenda
        Models.Reservation.Response.GetResourcesResponse response = _ReservationService.GetReservations(request);

        //alles van google agenda
        var allEvents = new List<EventModel>();

        var refresToken = RetrieveRefreshTokenAndRevoke.RefreshToken();

        if (refresToken == "ok")
        {
            var tokens = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ConstantJsonFileLink.TOKEN));

            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events"));
            RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest();

            restRequest.AddQueryParameter("key", $"{ApiKeys}");
            restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokens["access_token"]);
            restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            try
            {
                var responser = restClient.Get(restRequest);

                if (responser.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    JObject calendarEvents = JObject.Parse(responser.Content);
                    allEvents = calendarEvents["items"].ToObject<List<EventModel>>();
                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Coulden't connect to google agenda.");
            }
        }

        foreach (var e in allEvents.ToList())
        {
            schedulers.Add(new Scheduler
            {
                CompanyUserId = _siteEngine.CurrentUser.CompanyUserId.ToLower(),
                AppointmentId = e.Id,
                Text = e.Summary,
                Description = e.Description,
                StartDate = e.Start.DateTime,
                EndDate = e.End.DateTime
            });
        }

        List<Scheduler> schedulersGoogleAndTurnup = schedulers.Union(response.SchedulerData).ToList();

        //samen voegen van de agenda's
        response.SchedulerData = schedulersGoogleAndTurnup;

        //response voor javascript
        return Json(response);
    }
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list - this suggests there is a pageToken. It looks like you're just getting the first page.

Comment: try order by the start time,  remember that there is a max rows returned you may need to paginate over it.

Comment: Have you checked in the web app to ensure your insert worked?

Comment: can guys you give an example how i need to do it in c#?

Comment: @DaImTo how do i give the orderby do i give it with add parameters?

Comment: the insert works